# I'm Still Getting Gray Tiles In Android MapView?

Tags: android, eclipse, api, android-mapview

I'm developing and application using google maps MapView, and when I load it on my emulator, i get a grid of gray tiles, I've searched alot about that, most of the answers are saying it's the API key, but am sure mine is right, cause I've used it before and it worked, what shall I do?
Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yearb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yearb;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvMain);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0bwuRHiU6fZBoh9d0Z8taP6UvPiMybshuXzWioQ"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:id="@+id/mvMain"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me, I've done my homework searching loads of questions and answers, and can't find the reason for that.
Thank You.

**EDITED**
The issue ws with my emulator, it worked well on the device, but not the emulator, but when I changed the API level of the emulator, it showed well.

Comment: Do you have internet connectivity? Does the API key match the current certificate? If you've used this before, you could have used it with a different certificate.

Comment: Ofcourse I have internet connectivity, and yes, I've used the same certificate before on the same laptop and it worked very well.

Comment: What does the logcat say? Do you have an error along the lines of `Couldn't connect to factory client`?

Comment: @Raghav Sood Yes, it said that, what shall I do with this issue?
   '12-26 20:13:34.911: E/MapActivity(369): Couldn't get connection factory client'

Comment: Is that using the debug.keystore? Maybe eclipse was re-installed or the machine formatted? Best way to be sure about it is to re-generate the MD5 fingerprint and go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup and re-register it. ps.: also good to mention that google released a new version of the maps API that is infinitely easier to use and will soo be deprecating the V1, so maybe you should developed it on the v2 already.

Comment: @Budius Believe me, i regenerated my MD5 like 10 times already with all possible ways, and it's the same value, which the value I've used before, I've read about that V2 thing of google maps, but couldn't get it, and I need The V1 Google Maps, is there any problem if I'm using the V1?

Comment: I'm just trying to check all possibilities. As your code seems to be fine. Double check that your emulator is a Google APIs emulator (instead of just 4.01 or something like that). Also, I've always had problems with emulators, try it on a real device.

Comment: it's Target is Google APIs level 10
, and Thank for your efforts,
do you know what shall i do with the "couldn't connect to factory client" which appears in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Your **uses-library** Must be in Between  and . Replace your manifest with this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yearb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 </activity>
 </application>
```